# Connect to docker DB inside lambci docker-lambda

Tags: docker, aws-lambda

I'm using lambci docker-lambda to run my nodejs lambda locally. The lambda makes calls to a DB which, during development, runs in another docker container.

Because the lambda and the DB run in separate containers, accessing the DB via localhost:5432 doesn't work.

Question: **How to setup lambci so that it can access another local DB?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 ways to solve this:

1. The simplest is to attach the `lambci` container to your host's network (using `--net=host`). As long as your DB container is exposed on the host's (!) port `5432`, once `lambci` is on the host's network, it will be able to access the database on `localhost:5432`. **NB** the port may be variable as long as it's consistent, if the `DB` were exposed `9999:5432` on localhost, then `lambci` would access it on `localhost:9999`.
2. An alternative approach is to attach both containers to the same Docker network (you must first create the network `docker network create ${NAME}`). Under this approach, `lambci` would be able to reference the DB by the container name (perhaps `db`) and port, i.e. `db:5432`. Both containers would need to be run (on the previously created network) using something similar to `docker run --network=${NAME}...`. This is the mechanism that is used by Docker Compose.